# Area under a guassian with two known points using error function

Tags: probability

I am interested in a nice function to find the area of a section of a normalized Gaussian distribution. Let's say I have a normalized Gaussian distribution of standard deviation $\sigma$, mean $\mu$, and I am interested in the area centered at $\mu$ between +/- $t$ ( see below)
[image]

Is there a simple way to express this for any given $t$ using the erf? The ref from which I found the above figure uses

$$a_1 = 2 \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sigma} \right)  $$

But I don't think this expression is true for a normalized guassian. Moreover, can the $\textit{total}$ area be expressed by an error function?

Thanks, very new to statistics.

Comment: Which quantities in the diagram are 'known'?

Comment: all of them- t, sigma, and h are all known.

Answer (score 0):

This question has [already been answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187909). Note that you can compute the integral over a finite interval by means of the CDF $\Phi$:
$$\int_a^b \varphi(x)\,dx = \Phi(b) - \Phi(a)$$